# Unity: Проблема с передачей данных из одного скрипта в другой

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть gameobject `GJ-1` (родитель) в котором есть куча однотипных объектов, в этом `GJ-1` есть скрипт `"Script A"`, в нем хранится переменная со ссылкой на другой gameobject `GJ-2`. В каждой из дочерних объектов `GJ-1` есть `Script B`, которому нужна ссылка на `GJ-2`. Как мне получить эту ссылку? Т.е я хочу из скрипта B получить ссылку из скрипта A на `GJ-2`
Скриншот схемы - http://joxi.ru/xAeJw4XfpGqv5r

Таких объектов будут тысячи, т.е будут сотни `GJ-1` внутри которых будут десятки дочерних объектов, и к каждому `GJ-1` будет прилагаться СВОЙ `GJ-2`. 
В кратце: дочерние объекты должны получать данные из скрипта своего родителя, который в свою очередь получает данные от скрипта другого объекта.

Comment: может тебе нужен [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html) ..... и собственно всё ...... то есть в GJ-2  будет где-то в какой-то момент написано например `gameObject.GetComponentInParent<ScriptA>().gameobject2;`

Comment: вы немного не поняли вопроса, мне нужно из дочернего объекта GJ-1 получить ссылку на GJ-2 через объект GJ-1

Comment: и почему это не вяжется с тем, что я написал? ты в ребенке находишь компонент родителя, в котором есть ссылка на объект.. что не так с этой логикой?................... либо покажи лучше хотя бы скрины с иерархией и стрелками покажи где что находится и что куда ты хочешь получить и даже код можно привести. ибо по этому объяснению можно запутаться

Comment: вот такую связь хочу - http://joxi.ru/Dr8vpq9F4a6av2

Comment: на данный момент GameObject1 имеет ссылку на GameObject2, но childOfGameObject1 НЕ имеет ссылку на GameObject2 - в этом и проблема, я не знаю как подкрасться к GameObject2 именно через GameObject1, в обход него нельзя по причине того, что у всех дочерних объектов один и тот же скрипт используется

Comment: ну так в чем ошибка того, что я тебе написал? GameObject1  - это родитель, а childOfGameObject1  - ребенок этого самого родителя, так?

Comment: да, все верно. Но блин не совсем понял, у меня в GJ-2 вообще нет ничего, нет никакого кода, может быть ты имел в виду внутри childOfGameObject?

Comment: да,  именно так. `gameObject.GetComponentInParent<ScriptA>().gameobject2;` надо писать в `childOfGameObject1`......  просто я в твоих GJ-1 Gj-2 запутался. думал Gj-2 это именно ребенок родителя

Comment: вот скрипт потомка - http://joxi.ru/Vm6vEN3FDl5oLm , а вот родителя - http://joxi.ru/823bMy8hJLbvom но все равно выходит ошибка

Comment: `getSpawnPostion` - метод, а не поле ;-)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/v294zgyu3aP6lm добавил () все равно выходит ошибка :(

Comment: потому что у тебя там еще в начале написано `nameOfSpawn = ` - а это строка. Вот и говорит, что не может вектор в строку засунуть

Comment: вот я чудик, целый день провозился с этой ошибкой и глаза уже замылились! спасибо тебе за помощь! поставь свой ответ не как комментарий, а как ответ, чтобы я выбрал его правильным и ты баллы заработал)) хоть так отблагодарю тебя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gameObject.GetComponentInParent<ScriptA>().gameobject2;` надо писать в `childOfGameObject1`
за ответ спасибо Алексею!